# Arbitrary Set A a Function??

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Assume you have an arbitrary set A, let RA be the relation defined on A × Power Set(A) by,
for all a ∈ A and B ⊆ A,

"a RA B iff a ∈ B"

1.Let A = {0, 1}. Is RA a function? Justify?

2.Find a set A such that RA is a function.

does anybody have an idea of what to do? Im confused on trying to show its a function

The powerset(A) = {{0},{1},{EmptySet},{0,1}}

is RA a function then? because the X value is connected to a Y value?

Answer (score 0):

A relation in $A\times B$ is a function if each element in $A$ is related to only one element of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

1. $RA$ is not a function because $(1,\{1\})\in RA$ due to the fact that $1\in\{1\}$ and $(1,\{0,1\})\in RA$ because $1\in \{0,1\}$, and a function cannot have two values at a point.
2. Let $A=\emptyset$. Then every relation is a function.

Comment: How did you know that (1,{1})∈RA and (1,{0,1})∈RA ? I didnt understand what you did to get the answer

Comment: could you explain what you mean by "and a function cannot have two values at a point"

Comment: You need to look up the definition. I can't make it any clearer, sorry.

Comment: I don't think that a function defined over $\emptyset$ makes much sense. But the set $A=\{1\}$ also works.

Comment: @ajotatxe What i didn't understand is why did is {1} used? i though it is a function because 0 is connected to 1?

Comment: Functions on the empty set are perfectly valid. For every set there is a unique function from the empty set into that set.